# Should I accept my complete solution or another's advice that lead me to it?

Tags: support, accepted-answer, etiquette

I asked a question about [hierarchical data visualization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7111467/what-tool-generates-diagrams-from-sql-server-hierarchical-data/7150729#7150729) and received helpful pointers from another user.

The advice given was not a complete solution, but was enough to let me research a solution by myself. I upvoted the advice when I realized its value.

I have just now posted a solution for my own question. My answer includes code examples so that another user should be able to reproduce my solution. In my answer I have given credit to the user who advised me.

In a related question, [Jon Skeet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27669/which-answer-should-i-accept-that-which-solved-my-problem-or-that-which-solved) says "accept the answer which actually helped you the most". The other user's answer helped me to find my solution, but I think that my solution may help someone else more quickly in future, and serve as an example.

I feel like I should accept my solution. Would this be a breach of etiquette to the user who pointed me in the right direction in the first place?

Please advise.

Comment: You already upvoted the partial answer. That yours is better means you should accept it. Don't listen to bullies.

Comment: Just to be clear, no-one is bullying me into making a decision one way or the other. I just want to be sure of the accepted ettiquette of such matters.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32475/choosing-an-answer-based-on-the-actual-implemented-solution-or-what

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What Random says:

> You already upvoted the partial answer. That yours is better means you
>   should accept it. Don't listen to bullies.

A **complete** accepted answer will give the best help to future users with the same question.

Answer (score 8):

If you wish to reward the poster who helped you find the solution without marking it as an answer, you can [award a bounty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065/164291).

Comment: And/or add a message in your own answer that explains the situation, e.g. "This is the complete solution I used, but see John Doe's answer for how I arrived at it."